# What's Wrong with the codes?Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I can't figure out what's wrong with these two codes. I can't find out any difference.

```
for id,level,sex,content,laugh,comment in zip(ids,levels,sexs.contents,laughs,comments):
```

This works..

```
for id,level,sex,content,laugh,comment in zip(ids,levels,sexs,contents,laughs,comments):
```

This fails..

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "G:/pachong/爬虫/re_crawl.py", line 43, in 
>       get_info(url)
>     File "G:/pachong/爬虫/re_crawl.py", line 28, in get_info
>       for id,level,sex,content,laugh,comment in zip(ids,levels,sexs.contents,laughs,comments):
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contents'

Comment: For every original poster who gets a useful answer on Stack Overflow, there are something like 1,000 people who find it on search engines later. So, please put all details in the question text instead of referring to external links that may go away.

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally typed a period (`.`) instead of a comma (`,`). Python treats that as an attribute lookup on your `sexs` object. Just change `sexs.contents` to `sexs,contents`.

Comment: Oh my God, It's a really stupid mistake, thank your for answering this question..I maybe depend too much on errors offered by the compiler, That's make me lose the ability to find out where is wrong by myself....In fact,before I asked this question I have compared the texts with Online text comparison....It shows no difference......In a word,thanks.